# Cauchy distribution and relation to uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X be Cauchy distributed with parameters $\alpha$ and $ \beta >0$  i.e, the pmf of $X$ is $f(x) = \frac1{\pi} \cdot \frac{\beta}{\beta^2 + (x -\alpha)^2}$.

Let $Y$ be a random variable so that $(1,Y)$ is chosen at random from the line $\{(1,y) , y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and the connecting line between (0,0) and the x-axis in the interval $]\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$ contains equally distributed angles.

- Prove that Y is Cauchy distributed for $ \alpha = 0 $ and $ \beta = 1 $.
- Show that Y has no expected value.

I have no idea how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what does it mean that *connecting line contains equally distributed angles*

Comment: May be you mean that you draw a ray from $(0,0)$ in any arbitrary angle to the line $x=1$, and denote by $Y$ the $y$ coordinate of intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is like this. 
Note the relation between intersection $y$ coordinate and angle $\phi$ is like $\tan \phi = y$. Or $\phi = \arctan y$.

As you have that $\phi$ is uniformly distributed in $[-\frac{\pi}{2};\frac{\pi}{2}]$. You can tell that its density is $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}1_{\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]}\left(x\right)$.

Next write $$F_{y}(x)= P(y\leq x)= P(\tan \phi \leq x) = P(\phi \leq \arctan x) = F_{\phi}(\arctan x).$$So the density would be its derivative. Which is like $$(F_{y}(x))' = (F_{\phi}(\arctan x))' = f_{\phi}(\arctan x) \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}= \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}.$$

Comment: @ J. G. Thank you.)